# youtube Ad video not playing in embeded webview

Tags: android, iframe, webview, youtube

i have embedded a youtube link in the web view using iframe its working fine. But the problem is there are some video advertisment before the video,  but ad  is  not playing just the source video is playing directly . i need the ad video also to be played before starting the source video , ads are showing if i directly call the webview  method

> loadurl

The below code i used to embeb the youtube in iframe **(TYPE 1)**

```
  String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/P5OeT5r51co\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

but it not showing ads

but when i call **(TYPE 2)**

```
        displayYoutubeVideo.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5OeT5r51co");
```

it load the video with ads  in youtubesite inside the webview but i dont want the entire youtube site, only that player inside the webview.

what i want is to play the ads in the iframe methord **ie (TYPE1)** i used, how can i achieve that?i search the web but no result about this problem, can any one suggest a solution?

thank you